# How in useState iterate over an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have the following problem with a (hopefully) basic function of useState which I do not get yet. I wanna get a todo list with all the previously written tasks. I try to solve it in two ways:

First approach:

```
const [ favoritedList, setFavoritedList ] = useState([]);

const handleFavoritedVideo = (favoritedElement) => {
    setFavoritedList((previousFavorited) => {
        return [ favoritedElement, ...previousFavorited ];
    });
};
```

everything is working fine.

But when I try to do something like this:

```
const [ favoritedList, setFavoritedList ] = useState({favorited:[]});

const handleFavoritedVideo = (favoritedElement) => {
    setFavoritedList((previousFavorited) => {
        return [ favoritedElement, ...previousFavorited ];
    });
};
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: previousFavorited is not iterable

Why is this and how to fix it?

Comment: you cannot itterate `{favorited:[]}`, that is an object, try with `...previousFavorited.favorited`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useState({favorited:[]})` is initializing `favoritedList` to an `object`.

`previousFavorited` in `setFavoritedList` is whatever the current value of `favoritedList` is, which is an `object`. Therefore you are trying to use `...` on an `object`, which is not iterable like an array is and is invalid.

My recommendation would be to use `useState([])` to initialize `favoritedList` to a normal array, and then you can simply treat it as an array.

If you really must use an `object` for `favoritedList`, the solution would be to  return an object to keep the object structure consistent:

`return { favorited: [favoritedElement, ...previousFavorited.favorited] }`

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Treating it as an object instead of a array is, in my honest opinion, over-complicating things.

Answer (score 1):

In the second version, you are setting `favoritedList` to an object of the form `{favorited: []}`.

So in the function, your `previousFavorited` is not the list, but an object containing the list, which you should access using `previousFavorited.favorited`.

The affected code becomes something like:

```
return {favorited: [ favoritedElement, ...previousFavorited.favorited ]};
```

(Edit: there was a slight mistake in the code I wrote, corrected as per @mikeboharsik 's answer)